# Ubuntu for Pentium 4

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

Can I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS smoothly with following specs

Pentium 4-1.5ghz
RAM-1GB
Intel graphic card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will possibly leave Ubuntu for quite a while if you do that.
Not too long ago I had a Pentium 4 2.4Ghz PC with 1Gb RAM and integrated graphics.  I was running Ubuntu 12.04 I think; it was too slow, too, too slow and laggy (for my liking anyway!).  I now have a dual core PC with 4Gb RAM and when I tried Ubuntu 13.10 it was slick and fast.

My advice is: don't ruin your Ubuntu experience by using a 10 year old PC, but get a better one, you will then be able to enjoy using Ubuntu, I bought mine for £100, so it won't cost you too much.

Comment: I have installed Xubuntu 12.04 on a Pentium 4 desktop with 1GB RAM and a 64MB graohics card, and it runs smoothly with no problems at all, aside from the fact that this hardware has been compared to a space heater.

Comment: Good for you, that is something you can use with your PC, enjoy!

Comment: Not my PC; I'm helping the transition of Windows XP users to Linux. The term of support of Windows XP will soon be ending.

Comment: Oh I see, how many computers are you converting?

Comment: I don't know about the number of computers because I'm not doing it at a workplace. The computers are old personal computers running Windows XP, some of them requiring repairs as well.

Comment: Have you tried Lubuntu? or Puppy Linux? or Linux Lite? or Manjaro Xfce?

Comment: You should try Manjaro, it looks better than the default xfce.

Comment: I've tried Puppy Linux. There are some amazing things you can do with Puppy Linux by running the OS only from RAM if you have enough RAM. For my use case, I prefer Arch Linux to Manjaro because I would rather configure everything myself.